# Size parameter in plotly heatmap

Tags: plotly

In a contour map I can give the size parameter (https://plot.ly/python/reference/#contour-contours-size) to specify the step between each contour level. Is there any equivalent in a heatmap?

I have a contour map, and the user can specify the range and bin size. The default range is the range of the data, and the bin size is calculated by dividing that range into 12 bins. So for this example plot, the range is 353.1 to 360.7 and we have a bin size of 0.6, and I get the contour map shown below:

[image]

Now if the user entered a range of 350 to 370 and a bin size of 1, we'd have 20 bins, and the contour map would look like this:

[image]

Below is the heatmap I get for the same data with the defaults:

[image]

And here is what I get when I enter a range of 350 to 370 and a bin size of 1:

[image]

What I am looking for is a way to make the heapmap behave like the contour map with respect to the range and bin size.

Comment: Can you add an example image of what you are trying to achieve? Do you want steps in the colorscale?

Comment: I updated the question and added example images and an explanation of my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the desired behavior by setting [`zmin`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#heatmap-zmin) and `zmax` of your heatmap and adding a custom color range.

You can play with `rel_min` and `rel_max` which specify the upper and lower range of the values used for color range and the number of `bin`s

Note: The data for the volcano datamap was taken from [here](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/heatmap.html).

```js
var bin = 10;
var rel_min = 100;
var rel_max = 250;

var colorscale = [];
var color = Plotly.d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(["blue", "green", "red"]);

for (var i = 0; i < bin; i += 1) {
  colorscale.push([i / bin, color(i / bin)]);
  colorscale.push([(i + 1) / bin, color(i / bin)] );
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{
  z: heatmap,
  zmin: rel_min,
  zmax: rel_max,
  type: 'heatmap',
  colorscale: colorscale
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/heatmap.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just got around to trying this - it works perfectly! Thanks so much!